# "php lint" for a particular and slightly-earlier version of PHP?

Tags: php, shell, unit-testing, lint

A unit-test program seems to be complaining in this way:

> syntax error, unexpected 'const' (T_CONST), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)

... but so far I've not been able to find out *which source module* it's complaining about!

Well, I've got php 7.2 installed on this machine, and I'm told that the production environment is running 7.0.  I've got a handy shell-command that does `php -l` *("lint" == syntax check)* on every php file in the source directory, and it finds no errors.  So, I guess that I need to find a way to do a "lint" against the syntax of a previous version of PHP.

*But also ...*  Was there, in fact, a syntax-change of this kind between v7.0 and v7.2?  Doesn't seem too likely to me ...

Comment: Man, I don't know. You sure there wasn't a script changed somewhere? Change of environment during testing and/or modifying files? Syntax change for what exactly? Hidden character?

Comment: Download PHP 7 either locally or in docker. Will be best bet

Comment: I added a few extra tags there Mike. If they're wrong or irrelevant, either let me know or remove them yourself if you could please.

Comment: Well, let me just ask the crowd this:  "did such a syntax change actually occur between 7.0 and 7.2?"  Like I said, my one-liner to `find * -name '*.php | xargs php -l` produces no complaints when running PHP 7.2.  Yes, I could easily spin-up a docker container running PHP7.0 if someone would kindly tell me which image I should look for in the repo ...

Comment: ("Yeah, this is a weird one, all right ...")  `phpunit` tests suddenly started failing and it's giving me "unexpected exception" with a syntax-error message but it won't tell me where.  *And,* when I do the same `phpunit` run on my 7.2 box, it doesn't fail!

Comment: Something else:  I found a docker already installed with php7.0 on it, ran the same sort of `find` one-liner there and got no syntax error.  I'll see if I can coax `phpunit` to run there ...

Comment: *"And, when I do the same phpunit run on my 7.2 box, it doesn't fail!"* -  About that @MikeRobinson - So there stands to be some differences somewhere, since you *are* in different environments/machines/platforms. Have you checked if this isn't an encoding issue? Or different OS'. Btw, I only saw what you wrote in comments because I came back to it :-) I was curious to see if there was any new developments; doesn't seem to be. Can you not run each script in a browser and `var_dump()` stuff around? Enable error reporting / logs. You'll need to ping me, I won't be here forever *lol!*

Comment: No... it's something that just started happening ... automated "pipeline" tests on github ... and I've run phpunit on a 7.0 Docker container and it didn't fail there either.  So... "tomorrow is another day."

Answer (score 0):

PHPCompatibility allows you to check code for compatibility with a certain PHP version: https://github.com/PHPCompatibility/PHPCompatibility

It's useful to check if code breaks when updating PHP versions, and should help in your case.